# write a comma delimited list to a data grid view

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get a csv file into a data table but there are some things in the csv file that I am trying to omit from being entered into the data table, so I wrote it to a list first.
The csv files that i will using the software for have different sections in it for which I then split the whole list into the separate lists for those sections.
After all that was achieved, i needed to skip some lines in each list and wrote the final form i was happy with to lists respective to previous set of lists.

Now I hit a wall, I need to write each of the lists to a respective data grid.

---

```
   public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    String filePath = "";

    //list set 1 = list box
    List<String> lines = new List<String>();
    List<String> accountList = new List<String>();
    List<String> statementList = new List<String>();
    List<String> summaryList = new List<String>();
    List<String> transactionList = new List<String>();

    //list set 2 = dgv
    List<String> accountList2 = new List<String>();
    List<String> statementList2 = new List<String>();
    List<String> summaryList2 = new List<String>();
    List<String> transactionList2 = new List<String>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btn_find_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
           
            using (OpenFileDialog fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog()
            { Filter = "CSV|* .csv", ValidateNames = true, Multiselect = false })
                if (fileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    String fileName = fileDialog.FileName;
                
                    filePath = fileName;
                }
            
            try
            {
                if (File.Exists(filePath))
                {
                    lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath).ToList();

                    foreach (String line in lines)
                    {

                        String addLine = line.Replace("'", "");
                        String addLine2 = addLine.Replace("\"", "");
                        String str = line.Substring(0, 1);
                        int num = int.Parse(str);

                        if (addLine2.Length > 1)
                        {
                            String addLine3 = addLine2.Substring(2);

                            switch (num)
                            {
                                case 2:
                                    accountList.Add(addLine3);
                                    break;

                                case 3:
                                    statementList.Add(addLine3);
                                    break;

                                case 4:
                                    summaryList.Add(addLine3);
                                    break;

                                case 5:
                                    transactionList.Add(addLine3);
                                    break;

                            }

                        }

                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Invalid file chosen, choose an appropriate CSV file and try again.");
                }

                transactionLB.DataSource = transactionList;
                //var liness = transactionList;
                //foreach (string line in liness.Skip(2))
                //    transactionList2.Add(line);
                //Console.WriteLine(transactionList2);

                //var source = new BindingSource();
                //source.DataSource = transactionList2;
                //trans_dgv.DataSource = source; 


                accountLB.DataSource = accountList;
                
                
                summaryLB.DataSource = summaryList;
                
                
                statementLB.DataSource = statementList;

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Cannot load CSV file, Ensure that a valid CSV file is selected and try again.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot open File Explorer, Something is wrong :(");
        }
    }



}
```

---

EDIT 1:

the table has the following columns for the transaction lists (each of the lists have different columns) :

'Number' ,  'Date' , 'Description1' , 'Description2' , 'Description3' ,  'Amount' ,  'Balance' ,  'Accrued Charges'

an example of data in the lines of the transaction list:

9, 02 Sep, Petrol Card Purchase, Shell Kempton Park, 968143*7188 30 Aug, -714.45, -10661.88, 5.5

some liness do contain null values.

Comment: Hi. Could you post an example of the data going in and what you want to come out, please? It might be easier to help you then.

Comment: Please have look at edit 1 in the post that i have just made.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, it seems like you're wanting to get the value of the strings in your string list to appear in your DataGridViews. This can be a little tricky because the DataGridView needs to know which property to display and strings only have the Length property (which probably isn't what you're looking for). There are a lot of ways to go about getting the data you want into the DataGridView. For example you could use DataTables and choose which column you want displayed in the DataGridView. If you want to stick with using string lists, I think you could get this to work by modifying your DataSource line to look something like this:

```
transactionLB.DataSource = transactionList.Select(x => new { Value = x} ).ToList();
```

I hope this helps! Let me know if I've misunderstood your question. Thanks!